# Securing admin account, silly "solution" found

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

Hello fellow Drupalers,

I've been given the task of securing our admin account, on our websites (drupal 7) from outsiders.

My first thought was 2FA and I looked at some of the modules (tfa, google auth, etc) and they seem to be doing the job okay.

But as I was fiddling around I accidentally deleted the admin password.

Now I cannot login through the website with the admin account, but I can via `drush uli`.

Do you guys consider this to be an okay solution for securing the admin account?
I personally have my doubts about it, because it seems so simple...

Comment: How exactly did you delete the password?

Comment: Via the database, just fiddling around.

Comment: It was on my local dev version...

Comment: Curious, if you inspect element on password field and remove the `required="required"` and leave password empty does it log you in?

Comment: That was a good question. I've tested it, and I still cannot login even though the required has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not a solution I would rely on. "Securing admin account" is a wide topic that needs to be handled carefully, but answering specifically to your question, if what you want is to "protect" the password, you can run a cronjob that changes the password string to a random, SHA value, every X time. I've seen that in some clients.

Talking about MFA (2FA), yes, this adds a pretty solid and common layer of security. Also implemented it for some clients.

Comment: I think I've found part of the solution here: https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip

I've also found this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/947312 It has some good tips for securing the admin user.

Thank you for your answer.